# Problem using wx.StaticBitmap.SetScaleMode()

Tags: wxwidgets, wxpython

I am trying to resize a static bitmap whilst maintaining its aspect ratio. According to the docs, it looks like wx.StaticBitmap.SetScaleMode(Scale_AspectFit) should do the trick.

What do I need to import to make the ScaleMode enumeration (and Scale_AspectFit) available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, as of May 2020 (wxPython 4.1.0), it is not currently supported, although it is mentioned in the documentation.
I'd hazard a guess that if it is implementated, it will simply be `MyStaticBitMap.SetScaleMode(int)`

See: https://discuss.wxpython.org/t/setscalemode-and-genericstaticbitmap/34400

Comment: Thanks! I will investigate

Comment: Don't forget you can scale a wx.Image https://wxpython.org/Phoenix/docs/html/wx.Image.html#wx.Image.Scale